# What season-arc relevant elements are shown in S8E07 of New Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

I'm currently catching up on the final season of Doctor Who on Netflix Belgium, Season 8, before the BBC takes it down at the end of the month. I'm currently partway through Episode 7, Kill The Moon, and from what little I noticed so far, combined with the blurb, it contains an alien spider.

Now, I'm arachnophobic, and while I might be able to watch it, I'm not sure I might be able to sleep afterwards. The episode with the Donna Noble introduction already was a bit creepy, and the teaser at the end of S8E06 showed a quick image of the alien. I'm still not convinced that the nightmare about a giant spider crawling out of my ceiling later that night was because of my sleeping conditions and not because of that teaser.

I'm seriously considering skipping this episode and going to episode 8, but the season arc about people ending up in heaven when they die has piqued my curiosity and I don't really want to miss some vital clue about this, especially since it's the main meat of the season finale.

What parts related to Heaven are shown in the Kill the Moon episode of Doctor Who? Obviously spoilers are fine.

Comment: In addition to arachnophobic triggers, and lack of arc-relevant elements; the episode also requires some *fairly heavy* suspension of disbelief - to a degree that I'd recommend skipping it on the bad-science and lack of logic alone.

Comment: It's Dr. Who, it's all about _heavy_ suspension of disbelief, bad-science and lack of logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kill the Moon contains absolutely nothing that you need to know for the season finale. I'm pretty sure there isn't even a cameo of Heaven or the still mysterious characters associated with it.

So it should be perfectly safe to skip it.

Comment: Agreed. It's quite an interesting story in its own right (albeit pretty bonkers), but very stand-alone. Maybe worth mentioning the argument between Clara and the Doctor at the end? IIRC that hinges on to how they interact in the next episode.

Comment: @randal'thor - That argument is, for me, literally the only reason to be there.  It is one hell of a reason, too.

Comment: @randal'thor Can I just skip the parts of the episode that aren't that argument? Or would i not be able to follow the argument?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs You wouldn't be able to understand the argument fully if you knew nothing about the rest of the episode, but you could always read a short summary of the events of the episode online, e.g. at Wikipedia or Tardis Wikia.

Comment: @randal'thor I read the summary on Tardis Wikia, and apparently, the spider segment is only like the first half of the show, maybe 15 or 20 minutes. I've skipped until the moment Courtney kills the alien with her detergent and will watch from there.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Good luck with it! :-) Some interesting moral issues in there, although you do need a *lot* of suspension of disbelief.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't have much to do with the season finale, or the whole season arc, I still think you should watch at least the last 10 minutes, or so (no more spiders at that point. Don't worry). This episode kind of made tidal waves in the Doctor - Clara relationship that might have little to do with the finale. Besides, if you skip towards "Mummy in the Orient Express" you might not understand the beginning, or why they're there to begin with.